# InfluxDB query except last

Tags: influxql

Is there a way to create a InfluxQL query which selects all values except the last? My current InfluxDB query in Grafana looks like this:

```
SELECT sum("Counter_Volume") AS "Volume per hour" FROM "DataBeforeReset" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time(1h)
```